# How to run Geckodriver from an external request in an Ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, permissions, ssh, apache2, firefox

I have a Flask application running in an Ubuntu 16 server with Apache. It uses to WSGI to run. The main goal of this app is to scrape info from a 3rd website. To achieve this it uses Firefox and geckodriver. Geckodriver runs without any problem when I execute it from the terminal using ssh. However, when the app is executed from a domain I have in a web browser I get a connection refused exception. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with permissions but I have no idea how to solve it. Here are my environment specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- Mozilla Firefox 62.0
- Python 2.7.12
- Selenium 3.14.0
- Geckodriver 22.0

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about permission, but DISPLAY variable. The thing is Firefox couldn't find the screen and that's probably why it throws an exception. You might try to check by `echo $DISPLAY` in your ssh session and it is likely to be blank. The solution is setting DISPLAY to something.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

This tells X server to use the first monitor.

More information regarding [DISPLAY](https://superuser.com/questions/368530/understanding-x-windows-display-environment-variable-when-tunnelling)